# Textfield in the container view become non editable

Tags: ios, swift, uicontainerview

Textfield become non responsive. My container height is 300, and there is a Textfield which has y value: 310

But its not editable and non responsive. please guide me a through a proper solution.

Answer (score 2):

For one thing, it sounds like your text field is invisible (because it's outside of its parent view's bounds). If that's the case, make sure your constraints are set correctly so the text field is visible on the screen.

Another thing to check is that the property `userInteractionEnabled` of the text field, **and all its superviews**, is set to `true`.

Comment: Its visible, and also userInteractionEnbled : True

Comment: Both text field and its parent view have `userInteractionEnbled ` as `true`?

Comment: @CainaSouza asked a great question. If any of the view's parent views has `userInteractionEnabled` set to `NO`, then the view won't respond to user input.

Comment: I have been facing this issue and tried almost every answer on web but only this one worked, can you explain why this works as it will help in debugging future issues. Thanks.